# Conditional/dynamic gui (PyQt)

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt

I want to create a gui that its options-within depends on the user inputs. For example, I have totally 4 checkboxes in my gui (below snapshot); if user selects Group1 (in a separate gui, not shown here), the following gui appears but only "Group1, option1" and "Group1, option2" are shown (in another words, there will be no sign of Group2 labels and checkboxes).
In another scenario, if user select Group2 (again, in a separate gui, not shown here), the following gui appears but this time, only "Group2" labels and checkboxes appears, and "Group1" related stuff will hide.

[image: gui]

here is my code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(341, 216)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.pushButton_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 80, 111, 23))
        self.pushButton_1.setObjectName("pushButton_1")

        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 130, 111, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")

        self.checkBox_1 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(125, 50, 17, 17))
        self.checkBox_1.setChecked(True)
        self.checkBox_1.setObjectName("checkBox_1")

        self.label_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 50, 80, 13))
        self.label_1.setObjectName("label_1")

        self.checkBox_2 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(125, 80, 17, 17))
        self.checkBox_2.setChecked(False)
        self.checkBox_2.setObjectName("checkBox_2")

        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 80, 80, 13))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")

        self.checkBox_3 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox_3.setEnabled(False)
        self.checkBox_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(125, 110, 17, 17))
        self.checkBox_3.setChecked(False)
        self.checkBox_3.setObjectName("checkBox_3")

        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 110, 80, 13))
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_4")

        self.checkBox_4 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox_4.setEnabled(False)
        self.checkBox_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(125, 140, 17, 17))
        self.checkBox_4.setChecked(False)
        self.checkBox_4.setObjectName("checkBox_4")

        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 140, 80, 13))
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 341, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)

        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton_1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "OK"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Cancel"))
        self.checkBox_1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Auto"))
        self.label_1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Group1, option1"))
        self.checkBox_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Auto"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Group1, option2"))
        self.checkBox_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Auto"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Group2, option1"))
        self.checkBox_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Auto"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Group2, option2"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I can implement this by creating two GUIs; one only for "Group1" and the other one for "Group2". But I would prefer to have one general GUI that handle both scenarios.

Comment: Add a few `if`s and just set the `self.checkBox_...` to `None` instead of creating an object if the checkbox isn't desired (also check for `None` in `retranslateUi`).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I was thinking the same but I didn't know how to get user input as a variable in the gui's class; let's say I define a variable in the main gui class (for example, called "condition"); if condition=Group1, then I would enable Group1 and disable Group2, and vice versa for the other option. Unfortunately, when I add a variable in the gui class (for example, Ui_MainWindow(object, condition)) and then define conditon, it shows me:
TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases

Comment: You can use a normal class-bound or global variable `condition`. The way you wrote it you tried to derive the class `Ui_MainWindow` from `condition` which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelButscher for the advise. My main purpuse is to  use this gui inside another GUIs. For example, in GUI2, I use above gui but only "group1" will be visible. In another GUI, for instance GUI3, I call above gui but only allow "group2" to be visible. If I am not wrong, global variable is not applicable in these scenarios. I don't know about class-bound variable, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can separate the creation of those checkbox to another method. Then decide to pass which group to the method depended on user input.

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(341, 216)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.pushButton_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 80, 111, 23))
        self.pushButton_1.setObjectName("pushButton_1")

        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 130, 111, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 341, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)

        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    # Create function to add checkboxes based on input.
    def selectGroup(self, group):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        self.checkBox_1 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(125, 50, 17, 17))
        self.checkBox_1.setChecked(True)
        self.checkBox_1.setObjectName("checkBox_1")

        self.label_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 50, 80, 13))
        self.label_1.setObjectName("label_1")

        self.checkBox_2 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(125, 80, 17, 17))
        self.checkBox_2.setChecked(False)
        self.checkBox_2.setObjectName("checkBox_2")

        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 80, 80, 13))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")

        self.label_1.setText(f"Group{group}, option1")
        self.label_2.setText(f"Group{group}, option2")

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton_1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "OK"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Cancel"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    ui.selectGroup("1")  # Here you passed the input that you get from user.
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Dear @Ananta, thanks for your response (sorry for my slow reply). Your code is working perfectly fine when I manually select group. However if I want to use this gui inside another gui, I don't know how to do that. If we call this gui (your code) "GUI1". I want to use GUI1 inside another, for example GUI2. After importing GUI1 inside GUI2, I want to say GUI1(...,"Group1") or GUI1(...,"1") to choose "group1".
In another GUI (for example, GUI3), I want to use GUI1 but this time I want to choose group2. Can you please advise about this case?

Comment: As far as I understand, you want to choose group 1 for GUI2 and group 2 for GUI3. Then in UI2, you have to call `ui1.selectGroup("1")` and in GUI3, you have to call `ui1.selectGroup("2") `.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but unfortunately didn't work. I tried GUI1.Ui_MainWindow.selectGroup("1") but it gives me the error:
TypeError: selectGroup() missing 1 required positional argument: 'group'

Comment: To use `selectGroup`, you have to create instance of GUI1 by `ui1 = Ui_MainWindow()`, `ui1.setupUi(MainWindow)`, `ui1.selectGroup("1")`

Comment: Thanks Ananta. The error is gone but it doesn't do anything. I am using pushButton in GUI2 to open GUI1. After creating instance of GUI1, I am using below command to open GUI1:
self.pushButton_clicked.connect(GUI1.Ui_MainWindow)
which doesn't work. I think I need to use another method... or something else.

Answer (score 0):

Using @Ananta suggestions and with a little bit of tweaking, I managed to get the code working. I will elaborate my problems. I post the whole codes here, maybe someone finds it useful.

**Purpose**
To have a GUI (GUI1, for example) that have different appearance options. Below snapshots show Group1 and Group2 options

[image: Group1]
[image: Group2]

This is the code that @Ananta suggested and it's working very well.

**GUI1 code**.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    MainWindow.resize(341, 216)
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
    self.pushButton_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.pushButton_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 80, 111, 23))
    self.pushButton_1.setObjectName("pushButton_1")
    self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 130, 111, 23))
    self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
    self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 341, 21))
    self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
    MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
    self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
    self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
    MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
    self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

# Create function to add checkboxes based on input.
def selectGroup(self, group):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    self.checkBox_1 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
    self.checkBox_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(125, 50, 17, 17))
    self.checkBox_1.setChecked(True)
    self.checkBox_1.setObjectName("checkBox_1")

    self.label_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.label_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 50, 80, 13))
    self.label_1.setObjectName("label_1")

    self.checkBox_2 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
    self.checkBox_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(125, 80, 17, 17))
    self.checkBox_2.setChecked(False)
    self.checkBox_2.setObjectName("checkBox_2")

    self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 80, 80, 13))
    self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")

    self.label_1.setText(f"Group{group}, option1")
    self.label_2.setText(f"Group{group}, option2")

def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
    self.pushButton_1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "OK"))
    self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Cancel"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
import sys

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
ui.selectGroup("1")  # Here you passed the input that you get from user.
MainWindow.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Calling GUI1 in GUI2**

In order to do this, I did the following. To create instances of GUI1 in GUI2, I did what @Ananta suggested. Besides, I created a new "def" in GUI2. check "Group1_new_window" and "Group2_new_window" in the following code.

**GUI2 Code**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from numpy import *
from IQTools.IQ_and_RF import GUI1
import sys


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui_MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self._new_window = None

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(300, 200)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 100, 121, 23))
        self.pushButton_1.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_1.clicked.connect(self.Group1_new_window)
        self.label_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 104, 60, 13))
        self.label_1.setObjectName("label_1")

        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 140, 121, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.Group2_new_window)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 144, 60, 13))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_1")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton_1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Group1"))
        self.label_1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Group1"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Group2"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Group2"))

    def Group1_new_window(self):
        self._new_window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui1_new_window = GUI1.Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui1_new_window.setupUi(self._new_window)
        self.ui1_new_window.selectGroup("1")
        self._new_window.show()

    def Group2_new_window(self):
        self._new_window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui1_new_window = GUI1.Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui1_new_window.setupUi(self._new_window)
        self.ui1_new_window.selectGroup("2")
        self._new_window.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And this is the outcome; whenever I clicked Group1 in GUI2, the GUI1 appears as a new window that only shows Group1 options. Similar thing happens for Group.

[image: GUI2]